# Paraphrasing speed and heat capacity

Tags: heat, speed

Can we call [speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed) the *change in distance per time*?

Further, would you phrase [heat capacity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity) as *change in heat per temperature* or *change in temperature per heat*?

The reason for this question is that some people refer to heat capacity by *change in temperature per heat* and if I were to write down an equation based on that formulation, I would write it down as $C_{[p|V]} = \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial U}\right)_{[p|V]}$, which is not the way it's usually written.

Comment: I think speed IS called change in distance per unit time

Comment: I edited the question to be more explicit and stated the motivation for it as requested. Downvote should not be justified  now and *Hold* could be relieved now.

Comment: One question per question, already. These two ideas have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the process occurs, it can be described a few ways. Most generally, it is the **change in heat added per unit of temperature added**. In other words, it's $\Delta Q/ \Delta T$.

If you do this under a constant volume process, then you get the heat capacity at constant volume, which is the **change of internal energy per unit temperature**.

If you do it under a constant pressure process, you get the **change of enthalpy per unit temperature**.

Comment: I'm aware of the $C_V$ and $C_P$ processes, I'm really just referring here to the phrasing of the differential.

Comment: Definitely "heat per temperature". A higher heat capacity object requires more heat to raise its temperature by a degree Celsius.  "Temperature per heat" would be something else, like "heat elasticity/elastance" perhaps (terminology mine).

Comment: @TMOTTM I added the $C_V$ and $C_P$ definitions for completeness, but I also addressed your primary question and defined it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, speed is distance per time (m/s),
heat capacity is energy per temperature (J/K).